# Why am I getting cmath errors in terminal?

Tags: c++, cmath

I'm having trouble compiling my code in terminal the error specifically to cmath.

Here is the error codes.

```
area_calculator.cpp:45: error: call of overloaded `pow(int&, int)' is ambiguous
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:154: error: candidates are: double pow(double, double)
/usr/include/g++/cmath:512: error: long double std::pow(long double, int)
/usr/include/g++/cmath:508: error: float std::pow(float, int)
/usr/include/g++/cmath:504: error: double std::pow(double,int)
/usr/include/g++/cmath:495: error: long double std::pow(long double, long double)
/usr/include/g++/cmath:486: error: float std::pow(float,float)
```

When I run the code in cpp.sh it works well, but after compiling there is an error.

Here is my code

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {

    int optionNumber;
    int radius;
    const double pi = 3.14159;
    double circleArea;

    int length, width;
    double rectangleArea;

    int base, height;
    double triangleArea;

    if (n == 1) {

        std::cout << std::fixed;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
        circleArea = pi * pow(radius, 2);

    } else if (n == 2) {

        std::cout << std::fixed;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
        rectangleArea = length * width;


    } else if (n == 3) {

        std::cout << std::fixed;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
        triangleArea = (base * height * 0.5);
    }
}
```

Of course, there are some codes missing since this is a homework assignment, but I think this should help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says that call to pow is ambiguous because there is no direct overload for (int,int). There's no reason to use pow for squaring, just write `radius*radius`.

Comment: if you read the manual (google 'man pow') https://linux.die.net/man/3/pow you will see that there is no version of pow that takes 2 integers. The compiler can convert the int you gave to a double or a float but it doesnt know which conversion u want so it gives up (it doesnt know that both versions of pow will do the same thing)

Comment: I suggest you just multiply the number by itself, and not use `pow` at all for this program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I always suggest the same, but [compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/bgN7kR) can be really smart, nowadays.

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using? Can you compile with -std=c++11 at least?